# If $\lim x_{n+1}/x_n = L$ then $\lim x_n^{1/n} = L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Im trying to prove the following, and I think I am on the right track just not sure about a couple of things. Any help would be great!

> If $x_n$ is real, positive sequence and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = L$ then  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n}^\frac{1}{n} = L$

Since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = L$ then for every $\epsilon >0, \exists N$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N$:

$|\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n-11}} - L| < \epsilon \implies L - \epsilon < \frac{x_{n}}{x_{n-1}} < L + \epsilon$

Let $C_N = x_1\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right) \dots \left(\frac{x_{N-1}}{x_{N-2}}\right). $

We know from the above inequality that $(L - \epsilon)^{n-N} < \left(\frac{x_N}{x_{N-1}}\right)\dots\left(\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}\right) <(L + \epsilon)^{n-N}$

Multiplying by $C_N$, which is a product of positive reals gives:

$C_N(L - \epsilon)^{n-N} < x_1\left(\frac{x_2}{x_{1}}\right) \dots \left(\frac{x_{N-1}}{x_{N-2}}\right) \left(\frac{x_N}{x_{N-1}}\right)\dots\left(\frac{x_n}{x_n-1}\right) <C_N(L + \epsilon)^{n-N}$

$C_N(L - \epsilon)^{n-N} < x_n <C_N(L + \epsilon)^{n-N}$

I feel like it's practically done, not sure how to make the jump to $L - \epsilon <x_n^\frac{1}{n}< L + \epsilon$

**Given some suggestions and thinking and help from comments, this is my completion of the proof.**

Let $A = C_N^{1/n}(L-\epsilon)^{-N}, B =C_N^{1/n}(L+\epsilon)^{-N}$. Note that $A, B$ are positive (if we restrict $\epsilon$ to be small) Then it follows that:

$A^{1/n}(L - \epsilon) < x_n^{1/n} <B^{1/n}(L + \epsilon)$.

Taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$:

$L-\epsilon < \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n^{1/n} < L + \epsilon$.

$|\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n^{1/n} - L| < \epsilon$. Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n^{1/n} = L$.

Comment: ...Thus, for every $n\geqslant N$, $$A^{1/n}\cdot(L-\epsilon)<x_n^{1/n}<B\cdot(L+\epsilon)$$ with $$A=C_N\cdot(L-\epsilon)^{-N}\qquad B=C_N\cdot(L+\epsilon)^{-N}$$ When $n\to\infty$, $A^{1/n}$ and $B^{1/n}$ converge to $1$ hence...

Comment: Side note: This is a multiplicative variation on $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{y_1+\cdots +y_n}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$. Consider proving the following:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdot\frac{x_2}{x_1}\cdots\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}$$(Which, now that I look at it, is more or less what you've done).

Comment: @Did I see. But wouldn't this give $(L-\epsilon) < lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n^{1/n} < (L+\epsilon)$? I'm sorry if I am not seeing it.

Comment: Yes this would give $$L-\epsilon\leqslant\liminf x_n^{1/n}\qquad\limsup x_n^{1/n}\leqslant L+\epsilon$$ for every positive $\epsilon$ hence $$\liminf x_n^{1/n}=\limsup x_n^{1/n}=L$$ as desired.

Comment: @Did Yes that makes sense! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

From $(L - \epsilon)^{n-N} < \left(\frac{x_N}{x_{N-1}}\right)\dots\left(\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}\right) <(L + \epsilon)^{n-N}$
we have
$L - \epsilon < \sqrt[n-N]{ \frac{x_n}{x_{N-1}} } <L + \epsilon$.

Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{x_{N-1}} = 1$.

Comment: How does the first inequality get to the second?

Comment: Well, you have $\left(\frac{x_N}{x_{N-1}}\right)\dots\left(\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}\right) = {x_n \over x_{N-1}}$ and then take the $n-N$th root of either side. (I had a small typo.)